# It is possible to find out the version of Apache HTTPD when ServerSignature is off?

Tags: apache

I have a question. Can I find out the version of Apache when full signature is disabled. Is it even possible? If it is, how? I think that is possible because blackhats hacking big, corporate servers while knowledge of the version of the victim services is essential. What do you think? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well for a start there are two (or even three) things to hide:

1. [ServerHeader](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens) - which shows the version in the Server response field. This cannot be turned of in Apache config but can be reduced to just "Apache".
2. [ServerSignature](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serversignature) - which displays the server version in the footer of error pages.
3. X-Powered-By which is not used by Apache but used by back end servers and services it might send requests to (e.g. PHP, J2EE servers... etc.).

Now servers do show some information due to differences in how the operate or how they interpret spec. For example the order of response headers, capitalisation, how they respond to certain requests all give clues to what server software `might` be being used to answer http requests. However using this to fingerprint a specific version of that software is more tricky unless there was an obvious, observable change from the client side.

Other options include looking at server status-page - though you would hope any administrator clever enough to reduce the default server header would also restrict access to the server-status page. Or through another security hole (e.g. being able to upload load executable scripts or the like).

I would guess most hackers would more be aware of bugs and exploits in some versions of Apache or other web servers and try to see if any of those can be exploited rather than trying to guess the specific version first.

In fact, as an interesting aside, Apache themselves have long been of the opinion that hiding server header information is pointless "security through obscurity" (a point I, and many others, disagree with them on) [even putting this in their documention:](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens)

> Setting ServerTokens to less than minimal is not recommended because
>   it makes it more difficult to debug interoperational problems. Also
>   note that disabling the Server: header does nothing at all to make
>   your server more secure. The idea of "security through obscurity" is a
>   myth and leads to a false sense of safety.

And even allowing open access to [their server-status page](http://httpd.apache.org/server-status).